# setInterval time increases on every click

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have created a simple snake game with HTML5 and Javascript. I added a button to start/pause the game. But the problem is that whenever I pause and start the game by clicking the button, the speed of the snake increases. I am new to javascript. So I do not know exactly how the setinterval function works. Code is below:

**snake.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Snake game</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #snakeBoard {
            background-color: black;
        }
        #score {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="score">0</div>
    <canvas id="snakeBoard" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js"></script>
    <div><button type="submit" id="play" onclick="javascript:game();">Play</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**snake.js**

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var isPaused = false;
function game() {
        setInterval(draw,200);
        isPaused = !isPaused;
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById("snakeBoard");
    var cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasW = canvas.width;
    var canvasH = canvas.height;

    var snakeW = 10;
    var snakeH = 10;

    var score = 0;

    // deafult direction
    var direction = "right";


    //to color snake
    function drawSnake (x, y) {
        cxt.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        cxt.fillRect(x*snakeW,y*snakeH,snakeW,snakeH);

        cxt.strokeStyle = "#000";
        cxt.strokeRect(x*snakeW,y*snakeH,snakeW,snakeH);
    }

    //drawSnake(4,4);

    //create snake as array. By default contains four cells
    var len = 4;
    var snake = [];

    for(var i = len-1; i>=0; i--) {
        snake.push({x:i, y:0});
    }

    //create food   
        food = {
            x: Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasW/snakeW-2)+1),
            y: Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasH/snakeH-2)+1)
        };


    function createFood (x,y) {

        for (var i=0; i<snake.length; i++) {
            if (x==snake[i].x && y==snake[i].y) {
                food = {
                    x: Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasW/snakeW-2)+1),
                    y: Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasH/snakeH-2)+1)
                };
                createFood(food.x, food.y);
            }

        }

        cxt.fillStyle = "red";
        cxt.fillRect(x*snakeW,y*snakeH,snakeW,snakeH);

        cxt.strokeStyle = "#000";
        cxt.strokeRect(x*snakeW,y*snakeH,snakeW,snakeH);
    }

    //add user inputs
    document.addEventListener("keydown",getDirection);

    function getDirection(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != "right") {
            direction = "left";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != "down") {
            direction = "up";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != "left") {
            direction = "right";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != "up") {
            direction = "down";
        }
    }

    // check when the snake hits itself
    function checkSelfHit(x,y,snakeArray) {
        // for(var i=0; i<snakeArray.length-2; i++) {
        //  if(snakeArray[snakeArray.length-1].x==snakeArray[i].x && snakeArray[snakeArray.length-1].y==snakeArray[i].y) {
        //      return true;
        //  }
        //  return false;
        // }
        for (var i=0; i<snakeArray.length; i++) {
            if(x==snakeArray[i].x && y==snakeArray[i].y) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;

    }

     // function drawScore(score) {
        // cxt.fillStyle = "blue";
        // cxt.fillText("Score: ",10,50);
     // }

    function draw() {

        if (isPaused) {
            return;
        }

        cxt.clearRect(0,0,canvasW,canvasH);
        for(var i=0; i<snake.length; i++) {
            var x = snake[i].x;
            var y = snake[i].y;
            drawSnake(x,y);
        }


        createFood(food.x, food.y);


        // snake head
        let snakeX = snake[0].x;
        let snakeY = snake[0].y;


        if (direction == "left") snakeX--;
        else if (direction == "up") snakeY--;
        else if (direction == "right") snakeX++;
        else if (direction == "down") snakeY++;

        // if the snake hits the wall....... and for self hit checkSelfHit(snakeX,snakeY,snake)
        if (snakeX < 0 || snakeY < 0 || snakeX >= canvasW/snakeW || snakeY >= canvasH/snakeH || checkSelfHit(snakeX,snakeY,snake)) {
            return;
        }


        if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
            let newHead = {x: snakeX, y: snakeY};
            snake.unshift(newHead);
            score++;
            food = {
                x: Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasW/snakeW-2)+1),
                y: Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasH/snakeH-2)+1)
            }


        }
        else {
            // remove tail
            snake.pop();
            let newHead = {x: snakeX, y: snakeY};
            snake.unshift(newHead);
        }


        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;

    }
```

Also this is my first game project and first javascript project. So any other input or mistakes in code is appreciated.
Note: Please ignore some comments in the js file. Those were my mistakes. For my reference.

Comment: Every time you do `setInterval` you are creating a new interval timer. You have to save the return value of the function and cancel the old timer before starting a new one. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Look into clearInterval and setTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @fredrik already said you create a new interval with every execution of `game`
.

One way would be to control the interval by saving it in a variabel and clearing it before creating a new one:

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var isPaused = false;
var ticker = null;
function game() {
    if (ticker) {
        clearInterval(ticker);
        ticker = null;
    } else {
        ticker = setInterval(draw,200);
    }
    // isPaused = !isPaused; No need for this anymore
}

// ....
```

The other way would be to let `isPaused` do all the work like:

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var isPaused = true; // should be paused before clicking “play” in this case
var ticker = setInterval(draw,200);
function game() {
    isPaused = !isPaused;
}

// ....
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. I have one more query. Not related to the question but to the same game. My game function executes on second click but not on the first click. Where is the problem for that?

Comment: Same code as above. I just added the variable ticker. The problem of execution after second click was there even before I added the variable i.e., the problem was there with the code I pasted above.

Comment: I got it. It was because the function would be paused on the first click. I had initialized isPaused wrongly.

Comment: Here you go... 

Comment: Could you suggest a way on how to increase the timer of setInterval when a variable increases above a certain value?

Comment: Can you open a new question for this? Maybe others are interested in it, too and won’t find it here in the comments ;-)

Comment: Hey... Thanks for the reply. I got the answer. :)